# Using chromedriver_autodownload feature programmatically with appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

How to use `chromedriver_autodownload` feature from `Appium` desktop while initializing Android driver programmatically with `Appium` or while starting the `Appium` server from `appium-desktop`?

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/

Comment: Any updates on this question? I'm facing an issue where I cannot test a hybrid app due to this problem. I would like to avoid downloading the binaries to be honest.